# C# WPF - Build issues between Windows 7 & 8

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, data-binding, datacontext

Has anyone else found issues when building a .net4 C# WPF application in Windows 7 and then Windows 8 using VS2010?

For example, I have XAML TextBlocks bound to a DataContext, and when building the app in Windows 8 my UI bindings update as they should when the PorpertyChanged event is fired, but not on the Windows 7 PC. However, when the same application is rebuilt on the Windows 7 PC in VS2010 the UI bindings update on PropertyChanged event. I must point out that the data properties are updating behind the scenes, it's appears to be a UI issue.

I assume there must be differences in the .Net4 libraries between windows 8 and 7??? You'll have to forgive me, I'm fairly new ish to programming.

Many thanks,

Rob

Comment: Without seeing your XAML or code showing the properties, it's difficult to help you exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume there must be differences in the .Net4 libraries between windows 8 and 7??? You'll have to forgive me, I'm fairly new ish to programming.

Windows 8 comes with .NET 4.5, which is an in-place upgrade to .NET 4.  If you install .NET 4.5 on Windows 7, you'll likely get the same behavior.

It's possible you've hit one of the [.NET 4.5 compatibility issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx#wpf), so you're seeing different behavior on systems with 4.5 installed.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this Reed. I appreciate your input.